# TYPO3 Unit Tests via Scheduler

Tags: phpunit, typo3, scheduler

I have created various TYPO3 PhpUnit Tests (I'm using TYPO3 7.6.10). What I want to do now is schedule those tests so that they run, lets say, every 60 minutes, and I get an email if any test fails.

Is that possible with the TYPO3 Scheduler? If so - how?

Answer (score 2):

While it is certainly not impossible to achieve this, checks like this should be done way earlier. If broken code is deployed you could end up with a site which is broken for at least 60 minutes.

What you should do instead is use a CI (continuous integration) system to run unit tests on every single code change. There are various free options nowadays which are very easy to set up. You can do a quick search here on Stackoverflow to find suggestions and impressions.

This way you can ensure that broken code is not even deployed to your system anymore, as long as your coverage is good enough. It also ensures a proper separation of concern since a live website should not care about tests (you should not even have test code on the server) but only about serving requests.